# Complex Envelope

Tags: continuous-signals, complex, signal-energy, analytic-signal

Two signals have arrived with different phases. The sum signal is given by

$$x(t) = A\cos(2\pi f_ct) + B\cos(2\pi f_ct + \theta)$$

What is the complex envelope of $x(t)$? Need advice on how to get started.

What is the analytic signal $x_+(t)$? For this, can I not apply the $x(t) + \mathscr{H}\big\{x(t)\big\}$ to both $A\cos(2\pi f_ct)$  and $B\cos(2\pi f_ct + \theta)$, and just add the result?

Comment: Hi and welcome. A rule here is that any question with homework problems needs to contain the attempts at solving them. Please edit your question with what you've tried so far and where you're stuck, and I'm sure you'll get help and guidance!

Comment: Homework?  Please _edit your question_ with the work you've done so far, or if you're utterly stuck, tell what you _do_ know.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ constant?  Doesn't look like your envelope has much shape.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes, A & B are constants... same signals, just the 2nd one comes in with a phase

Comment: There are trig identities that you should make use of.  This is hardly a complex envelope problem.  Not a complex-valued signal (i suppose $A$ and $B$ could be complex?) and the envelope is a constant function.  It's just a sinusoid with an amplitude and a phase.

Comment: @Jdip You may also feel free to give hints as to how I can get started or arrive at the solution. Any words of wisdom relating to the problem (aside from the initial comments) help.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson the answer I think is (A + Be^j*phi)*e^(j*2*pi*fc*t)

Comment: I think you're confusing the term *"Complex envelope"* with *"Analytic signal"*.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson correct. I need both actually, but the complex envelope is what I said it would be in my previous comment, solution wise. I still have to find the analytic signal to the original x(t). Please advise if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that

$$\cos(\omega_0t)=\textrm{Re}\left\{e^{j\omega_0t}\right\}$$

it is straightforward to write down the analytic signal of $x(t)$.

The analytic signal has the form

$$x_c(t)e^{j\omega_0t}$$

and you have

$$x(t)=\textrm{Re}\left\{x_c(t)e^{j\omega_0t}\right\}$$

where $x_c(t)$ is the complex envelope. Judging from the comments under the question, you know everything you need in order to obtain the analytic signal as well as the complex envelope.

Comment: what if I have two different fc values ie f1 and f2?

Comment: @Gotz2bril: You could better ask that as a new question. This question has been answered as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the third row of `Table 1` at:

https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/635.php

would be helpful to you.